# Delete function / stored procedure from another stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures

I am trying to delete a function / stored procedure from another stored procedure. **Is this possible..?**

I am getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1357
Can`t drop or alter a FUNCTION from within another stored routine
- or -
Can`t drop or alter a PROCEDURE from within another stored routine
```

Comment: Error message clearly says **NO**. Why do you even want to do this ?

Comment: It's just for info, not more than that :)